# auth0 after successful login error 500 when redirection

Tags: angular, auth0

the login going successfully but I get unauthorized when redirect to path after the login.

```
public signIn(): void {
    this.authService.loginWithRedirect({
      appState: {target: 'path'}
    })
}
```

Using angular 16.1.5

The expected result is when I successful login to auth0, the auth0 must redirect to path component after.

What happen is I get unauthorized(error 500 ) after successful login.